# How to get results from my Rails 3 controller with javascript and passed in parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get some results from my controller based one some javascript variables but I haven't the foggiest idea on how to do this.

So far I have:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/shops?state=' + state + '&city=' + city , type: 'get', dataType: 'html',
        complete: function(request){
         $("#shop_results").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shop_results') %>");
        }
    });
```

Which according to my rails console IS hitting my controller and sending in the parameters but my controller:

```
  def shops
    @maps = Map.where("state LIKE ?", "#{params[:state]}")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

my view:

```
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 980px; height: 400px"></div>

  <div id="shop_results">
    <%= render :partial =>"shop_results"%>
  </div>
```

and the shop_results partial has the code displaying the array:

```
  <ol class="shop_list" style="background:blue;">
    <% @maps.each do |m| %>
      <li><% link_to m.shop_name ,"#" %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
```

Butttt nothing is showing up in my view where the partial is called

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "it's not returning anything in the console", but if you're doing a "like" query, wouldn't you want some % signs in there? Are you attempting to do state name completion?

Comment: I fixed that and got my controller to return the correct array but I still cant show the results. I edited my post

Comment: Well, you'd want to put the event handler in `success`, not complete, first of all :) Then you need to render the partial in the controller, and just set the results DOM element's HTML to the result. As it stands, you're making the request, but after the request is over and control has returned, you're just rendering the partial--no longer connected to the request that sets the `@maps` variable. (There are a ways to do all this.)

Comment: Ok that makes sense, how do I render the partial in the controller?

Comment: `format.html { render :partial => ... }` etc. It doesn't *have* to be a partial, although you'd likely need to turn off its layout if it isn't.

Comment: adding that to that line causes my page to display nothing at all, just a white page. I added what's in my view (sans most of the javascript dealing with the google maps API). Should I being using the format.js to call some jquery to add the content? Im not sure how to do that with an array. I added my view to the question too

Comment: ah I got it. I made a js file that renders the partial for me